# vuex persisted state not working with vue router navigation guard

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

I've added `vuex-persistedstate` as defined in documentation. *(confirmed and working)*

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
        auth,
    },
    plugins: [VuexPersistedState()]
});
```

I've set up a router navigation guard to redirect to home page on login

```
/* Auth based route handler */
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.meta.hasOwnProperty('requiresAuth')) {
        if (to.meta.requiresAuth === true) {
            let isAuthenticated = authStore.getters.isAuthenticated
            if (isAuthenticated(authStore.state) === true) {
                next()
            } else {
                next({name: 'login'})
            }
        } else {
            let isAuthenticated = authStore.getters.isAuthenticated
            console.log(authStore.state)
            if (isAuthenticated(authStore.state) === true) {
                next({name: 'home'})
            } else {
                next()
            }
        }
    } else {
        next()
    }
})
```

The vuex persistedstate restores store from local storage but not before navigation guard!

I can provide any necessary part of the source code for evaluation. Please comment your request as needed. Experimental solutions are also welcome. This is just a personal training application for me!

Help is appreciated!

Comment: what is the relative order of Vue.use() for vuex and vue-router ? You might want to try flipping it (for first cut).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. In fact, it looks like that the relative order of vue-router and vuex does not even matter. It looks odd to me that you would try to send the state of the store to a getter, while the getter itself has access to the store, so maybe something funky is going on there?

Comment: Accessing a getter directly without a computed scope doesn't pass getter with a state. accessing getter from the store object is just like accessing exported function from a file. Hence calling getter in such a way assigns state object as undefined. Hence I need to pass state object.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is probably of no use to @Vaishnav, but as I wen't down the same rabbit hole recently I figured I'd post a workaround I found for this here as this was the only post I found that asked this issue specifically.

in your `store/index.js` You need to export both the function and the store object.

Change this :

```
export default() => {
  return new vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  strict: debug,
    modules: {
      someMod 
    }, 
    plugins: [createPersistedState(persistedStateConfig)] 
  }); 
};
```

to:

```
const storeObj = new vuex.Store({
  namespaced: true,
  strict: debug,
  modules: {
    someMod
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState(persistedStateConfig)]
});

const store = () => {
  return storeObj;
};

export {store, storeObj}
```

Then also, as you have now changed the way you export the store you will also need to change the way it's imported.

Everywhere in your app you've imported the store ie: in `main.js` -> `import store from '@/store'` excluding the `router.js` you will need to change to `import {store} from '@/store'`

And in your `router.js` just `import {storeObj} from '@/store'` and use that instead of `store` in your router guard ie: `storeObj.getters['someMod/someValue']`

Comment: But does arrow function implementation of state does make it dynamically change on mutation? I went through with the problem and found that the state actually wasn't changing and hence provided the solution in the Vuex docs for how to use store globally.

Answer (score 0):

I found a **working** example.

As the router isn't a component.

> In router config file -
>
> ```
> import authStore from '@/stores/auth/store'
> ```
>
> Instead -
>
> ```
> import store from '@/store'
> ```
>
> in navigation guard, I ***replaced***
>
> ```
> let isAuthenticated = authStore.getters.isAuthenticated
> if(isAuthenticated(authstore.state) === true){...}
> ```
>
> with -
>
> ```
> let isAuthenticated = store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']
> if(isAuthenticated === true){...}
> ```

And now this **works** like charm...